# Custom Hold Trigger WP7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, expression-blend

Is there a way to lengthen the hold trigger? Currently you need to press and hold for about 2 seconds. I need it to last about twice as long. Is there a property I can edit for the function? Or do I need to create a custom trigger some how.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the GestureListener ([GestureListenerStatic.cs](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/71382#1510228)) in the Windows Phone 7 toolkit, and follow that pattern to build your own Hold event from the TouchPanel events.